# My second StringVar fails to show text, shows blank

Tags: python, tkinter

I was writing a pixel editor in Tkinter, to practice Tkinter and GUI programming. And I was thinking to add a "bottom frame" to show informations like the current tool, the canvas size, etc. But for some reason, the second defined StringVar doesn't seems to work, while the first one works just fine. By this, I mean the code runs just fine but the second StringVar doesn't show anything.

Here is the code, for the bottom frame so far:

```
# Bottom frame
ttk.Style().configure('Interface.TFrame', background='#dbdbdb')
bottomframe = ttk.Frame(root, style='Interface.TFrame')
bottomframe.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=(N, S, W, E), pady=4)

# An indicator that shows the current selected tool.
toolname = StringVar()
toolname.set('paint tool')

tool_label = ttk.Label(bottomframe, textvariable=toolname, width=11, background='#dbdbdb', anchor='center')
tool_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(W, E), padx=2)

# A thin separator.
ttk.Separator(bottomframe, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(N, S, W, E))

# An indicator that shows the canvas size.
cvsize = StringVar()
cvsize.set('50x50 px')

cv_size_label = ttk.Label(bottomframe, textvariable=cvsize, width=11, background='#dbdbdb', anchor='center')
cv_size_label.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=W, padx=2)
```

So, why it's not working? The first and the second indicator look nearly same (except the bind operation) and the second one still fails. I also tried removing the first, but it also failed.

I have no idea how can I fix it. I think, I am either missing something and using the StringVar wrong, or there is something in my code that causes this behavior.

So, how can I fix it? And also, why it's happening?

EDIT: Removed the function definiton part. It wasn't really part of the question.

Comment: Please provide a working [mcve]. This code appears to be part of a class definition, but you don't show enough code for us to know for sure. You also don't show how `self.canvas` is created or added to the screen.

Comment: My guess is that this is because you aren't saving a reference to the variables `toolname` and `cvsize`. Try changing them to `self.toolname` and `self.cvsize`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @BryanOakley. I removed the ```self.canvas``` part, which was a _tkinter canvas object_ that I used for painting. It was actually irrevelant for my question but somehow I forgot to remove it. I sadly couldn't find a way to reproduce it, without running the whole thing. But I think you're right. When I add the references, texts just show up right. I defined some functions to control the _textvariable variables_, which also fixed the problem. So, thanks for your help. I wasn't aware that keeping references was so important.

Comment: Now I only had one more question: Is this happening to free memory? Because when I try to ran it as a separate example, it just works fine, only fails in the real code.

Comment: Yes, it's part of python's standard method of freeing up memory that it thinks isn't being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally understood the reason behind this behavior, thanks to @BryanOakley. Python was removing those *unusued* variables to free up memory. Because even though they are *used* in tkinter window, it doesn't really matter for Python, since the `mainloop()` is what *organizing* the window. So, it is necessary to *save a reference* of the variable somewhere, to prevent Python from removing it. And the easiest way of doing this, is saving the variable with `self`. Which won't get removed even after the class definiton ends.